# Custom theming: How to list multiple content types in the same page and use regions too

Tags: views, theming, 8

I created two content types: **articles** and **press releases** and I want to display those in the same page. I also am developing a custom theme.

So I created a view for that with the machine name `press_release_list`, created a template for it: `views-view--press-release-list.html.twig` and it works perfectly.

The problem is, I cannot make use of regions. I mean, I have `content` and `side_menu` regions and I want to add a twitter feed to the side menu. I add the block through "block layout" menu, it can be configured to be displayed on **article** and **press release** nodes however there is no option for the view I created...

I'm quite new to Drupal so what would be the best way to do this, is there a way to display the block on the view or is there a better option than creating a view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In block layout the visibility for content types works only, if the content type is a route match. That means, you have requested a node with that specific content type through the url.

It does not work for nodes that are displayed as result of a view.

To configure the visibility for a view you can define in the tab "Pages" the url of the view or a pattern of urls, that matches multiple views.

Comment: I tried that actualy, it's not working. In the page settings for the view the path is set to **/what-is-on-the-agenda** and in the block's configuration pages tab url set to **/what-is-on-the-agenda** with "show for the listed pages" option selected. Cleared the caches too... Am I missing smt.?

Comment: did you remove all other restriction, especially that for content types?

Comment: Yep that seems to be the problem, removed the content type restrictions and it's fine now.